# "/usr/bin/sed: illegal option -- 2" error when applying a .sh format patch on Mac OS X 10.9

Tags: patches

I tried to execute an offical SUPEE-6788 patch file. However, I got sed-related errors as following:

```
$ sh /path/to/PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-10-26-11-37-50.sh        
sed: /path/to/PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-10-26-11-37-50.sh: No such file or directory
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
sed: /path/to/PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-10-26-11-37-50.sh: No such file or directory
sed: /path/to/PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-10-26-11-37-50.sh: No such file or directory
Patch was applied/reverted successfully.
/usr/bin/sed: illegal option -- 2
usage: sed script [-Ealn] [-i extension] [file ...]
       sed [-Ealn] [-i extension] [-e script] ... [-f script_file] ... [file ...]
```

My environment is Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Darwin 13.4.0)

Any ideas?

Comment: How did you copy/download the patch file? I've seen errors like this when the character encoding of the file was wrong.
Try to re-download the patch file.

Comment: @AnnaVölkl I re-downloaded the patch file via Firefox 40, but it seems to be exactly same to failed one: `MD5 (/path/to/PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-10-26-11-37-50_bad?.sh) = e9b3a9af35269254b432e32e645bc2e7
MD5 (/path/to/PATCH_SUPEE-6788_CE_1.9.2.0_v1-2015-10-26-11-37-50.sh) = e9b3a9af35269254b432e32e645bc2e7`

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue because the patch file was not in my Magento base directory. So what I did was I copied the patch file into my Magento base directory and ran it from there.